# How to create navigation menu with backbone?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js

I'm starting to learn Backbone.js and can't figure out one thing: In a typical rails app, I have a layout view and a nested view. My layout usually contains navigation links that are processed by rails routing.

How do I do the same with Backbone? I'm using Rails 3.2 and eco templates.

- Should I create nested templates in eco?
- Should my navigation links be plain html links with a href or should the navigation be event driven?

For example I have a list of categories on the left, and a category items on the right. I want my categories to be shown on every view and the corresponding category items (with a URL in browser corresponding to selected category) too.

Please point me to right direction, because most tutorials on the Web are 'todo' style applications with no navigation at all.

Thank you.

**UPDATE**
Turns out, my question wasn't clear, so let me narrow it down.

**How can the concept of RoR layouts be applied to backbone.js applications?**

And I'm curious about two possible ways of navigation:

- create

  %a{:class => "customers", :href => "#customers"} Customers
- handle ".customers click" event in my view

Which way is better?

Comment: There are several questions in here, let me try to redefine them: **1) how to render a "Collection" with nested "Models"?**, **2) "Backbone.Routers" or "Server requests"?** I think the 2) have to be answered by you due depends in what you are looking for. If 1) is what you want try to redefine your question.

Answer (score 1):

> And I'm curious about two possible ways of navigation:
>
> create %a{:class => "customers", :href => "#customers"} Customers
>
> handle ".customers click" event in my view
>
> Which way is better?

neither is better until you know the specific context in which you are working. they are simply options for achieving your goal and desired functionality.

there are times when both should be used, as well. for example, if you are supporting search engine optimizations and accessibility.

Here are some better questions to ask:

- Which of these will be the simplest thing that can get the job done? will it be more code to write the route handler, or the click handler?
- Will the route handler tightly couple the functionality to a router, when I don't need that?
- Do I really need a route for this link, so that people can bookmark it and come back to it directly?
- Will a click handler cause my code to jump through several hoops of calling other objects that aren't directly related, or can I use a simple event to cause the other objects to run?

There isn't a single correct answer to any of these questions. I recommend trying many different ideas when you can. Keep in mind that you will likely change your answer as you develop new features. The answer that you want, today, won't be what you need tomorrow. But that shouldn't stop you from picking an answer now and moving on. Pick one, put it in place, and when you need to change it, change it.